# Swift Compiler thinks that a property is optional (tintColor in UINavigationBar), even though is defined as non-optional

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, option-type

```
    if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.tintColor = Color.grey1.uiColor
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.createImage(withColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.92)), for: .default)
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            .font: Font.monoBold.uiFont(ofSize: 17),
            .foregroundColor: navigationBar.tintColor
        ]
    }
```

The compiler flags `navigationBar` as non-optional `UINavigationBar`.
This makes sense because we are `if let` unwrapping it

In the interface for `UINavigationBar`, it has this property `tintColor`

```
open var tintColor: UIColor!
```

So it seems like `navigationBar.tintColor` would be non-optional right?

However, the compiler decides to disagree here:

[image]

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIColor?' to 'Any'

Why does the compiler all of the sudden think that `tintColor` is an optional `UIColor?`

Comment: An implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO) is an *optional*.  Swift will only force unwrap it for you if it is used in a place that only a `UIColor` can be used.  Since the dictionary has type `Any` as the value type, and `Any` can handle anything, you'll have to force unwrap `navigationBar.tintColor!`.

Comment: Check the linked duplicate.  Rob explains it very well.

Comment: Thanks for the info folks!  I also found this article as a result, which has a lot of good examples and explanation as well: https://krakendev.io/blog/when-to-use-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Comment: That document is a little out of date.  Check out this [Swift Evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) document for more info.